# Delphi XE2. ActiveX. How to call GetIDsOfNames for resolve Method ID for few methods?

Tags: delphi, activex, delphi-xe2

How to call GetIDsOfNames for resolve Method ID for few methods? It works fine for resolve only one or first-one MethodID.

My code right now:

```
   pDisp         : IDispatch;

   intResult     : HResult;
   NameCount     : integer;

   DispIDs       : array [0..2] of Integer;

   WideNames     : array of WideString;
   I             : Integer;
   Names, Src    : PAnsiChar;
   N             : array [0..2] of PAnsiChar;

   begin
          pDisp := CreateOleObject (edtPrgID1.Text);

          if VarIsNull (pDisp) or VarIsEmpty (pDisp) then
                 Exit;

          //-=-

          NameCount := 3;
          Names := 'doF4' + #0 + 'doF5' + #0 + 'doF6' + #0;

          //-=- 

          SetLength (WideNames, NameCount);
          Src := Names;
          for I := 0 to NameCount - 1 do
          begin
                 if I = 0 then
                       WideNames [I] := UTF8ToWideString (Src)
                 else
                       WideNames [NameCount - I] := UTF8ToWideString (Src);
                 Inc (Src, StrLen (Src) + 1);
          end;

          intResult := pDisp.GetIDsOfNames (GUID_NULL, WideNames, NameCount, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, @DispIDs);
```

I am trying to work with my own ActiveX COM (DLL) component. All method 100% exists and valid.

I am not sure why, but in **DispIDs** I always get result only for first method (in my sample “doF4”), for all other methods I get -1.
So, **DispIDs** after execution **pDisp.GetIDsOfNames** looks like **(205, -1, -1)**.

Comment: Instead of "DispIDs       : array [0..2] of Integer;" i also try 
"array [0..2] of TDispId" -- but result the same

Comment: What do you see if you put a watch on `Widenames` as you call `GetIDsOfNames()` ?

Comment: WideNames = ('doF4', 'doF6', 'doF5')

Comment: What do you get if you call `GetIdsOfNames` once for each of `doF4`.. `doF6` in turn - that is instead of passing an array of methodnames?

Comment: I get right result. For example 205, 206, 207.

Point is: if I understood documentation right, GetIDsOfNames able to resolve Method ID for few methods at once.... and this is what I willing to use.

Comment: No, I dont think so.  Each call returns the ID of a single method by name (if I remember correctly).  Does `doF4` take 2 parameters by any chance ?

Comment: I see your point. I think i understood now my mistake... According to documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221306.aspx "rgszNames -- Passed-in array of names to be mapped.", however, according the same documentation this function does: "Maps a single member and an optional set of argument names " ... so, it's for resolve ONE method with optional parameters -- not for few methods.... THanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `GetIDsOfNames()` once for each method. [The  documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains why in its description of the output parameter:

> The first element represents the member name. The subsequent elements represent each of the member's parameters.

So to get IDs of three members, rather than one member and two of its arguments, you need to call it three times.